# Why is Multisim showing an error for my LED circuit?

Tags: led, multisim

[image: schematic from Multisim]

The components that I can use in this project are:

- 555 IC
- two 100 nF capacitors
- 9 LEDs
- one BC547BP NPN transistor
- four resistors - two 1.6 kΩ, one 1kΩ, one 100 Ω

I use Multisim to simulate this circuit, but I don't know what is the problem occurs. The collector resistance is connected to the 12V Dc source or ground? And LED can be connected like this way?

Comment: Have you researched the unholy benefits of putting LEDs in parallel?

Comment: @WeiHungChew: The error has less to do with the circuit, and more to do with the simulator software.

Comment: It's not good practice to have LEDs in parallel with a single current limiting resistor. The software might recognize that none of your LEDs have a dedicated resistor.

Comment: @Jay: "Convergence" is a problem that usually occurs when the simulator can't find a solution for the various partial simulations.  It isn't specific to LEDs.  I most often run in to it when the circuit frequency and the simulation  time step size are incompatible.

Comment: @WeiHungChew -- Looking at your prior question (thanks, SamGibson), I don't even see the need for the BJT. If it is required, I'd just ground it like a dead bug somewhere or else use it as a diode-connected BJT to drop a little voltage (in a special spot that comes to mind.) The whole enterprise, including dealing with LED vagaries such that their currents are under good management, can be done beautifully with everything and without the BJT. This includes a 50% duty cycle, too. It's a nice question requiring barely a few seconds' thought.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get error 404? Or Internal server error? 503? What is error? You don't try to analyze anything at all. When describing problems, please, be specific. What result did you want to get? What do you get? What was your reasoning of doing things the way you did? What are you unsure about? You should have a minimum of two paragraphs of text, I can't look into your head.

Regarding your thing here. If you output HIGH to transistor base, transistor conducts, LEDs go off because their positive terminal is grounded via transistor (in fact, it will be like 0.2V, because collector-emitter is around 0.2). When you output LOW to the base of transistor, you have enough voltage on the collector (which is LED positive) to light up the LEDs. However, no two LEDs are equal, we live in no-so-perfect world. Some of them will have lower "opening" voltage. So most of the current will flow through some or even one LED. Every LED needs its own resistor, it's the only possible proper way to do that.

Comment: Why on Earth would a simulator throw an internet error (404 and 503 are errors that a web server would generate?)

Comment: Not to pile on (though I agree with @JRE's comment), it is not the case that the only proper way to operate the LEDs is to provide a separate resistor for each one. As it turns out, the OP's earlier question (noted by SamGibson's comment above) is actually a good test for one's imagination and ability to see things in various ways. The assigned problem can be properly solved with the parts provided, including good current management for the LEDs that accounts for their variations. In fact, all that without the BJT, too.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs can have wide tolerances for bulk resistance and this leads to imperfect current sharing.

They also have a negative temp coefficient on voltage, so if one has a lower voltage at the target current, it will increase in temperature and drop in voltage thus drawing a bigger share of the current. Since a temp is not modelled here it leads to a convergence error.

Adding a resistor for a 0.1V ~-.3V drop or whatever the tolerance of the batch is will normalize the current sharing. Since a 20 mA LED has an Rs value from 15 Ohms for W/B to 10 Ohms for R/Y LEDs this can be as low as a few Ohms and may or may not be needed, depending on the quality of matching. Just don't assume they are matched.

In reality, modern LEDs in batches can be well-matched in the same batch and you can create a 3x3 matrix or 3S3P with smaller Resistors for each string.  So instead of 1S9P with one Rs=1k from 12V , us 3S3P and compute the  residual V/I series R for each string.